# Firestore: how can read data from outside void onComplete methods

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read data from Cloud Firestore:

```
      firestoreDB.collection("events")
                .whereEqualTo("type", eventType)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                           List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();

                           for(DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                              Event e = doc.toObject(Event.class);
                              e.setId(doc.getId());
                               eventList.add(e);
                           }
               //do something with list of pojos retrieved

                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
 });
```

Since onComplete is a void method, how can I get eventList from outside methods?

For example, I tried:

```
List<Event> ReadCollection()
{
   final List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
firestoreDB.collection("events")
                    .whereEqualTo("type", eventType)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();

                               for(DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                                  Event e = doc.toObject(Event.class);
                                  e.setId(doc.getId());
                                   eventList.add(e);
                               }
                   //do something with list of pojos retrieved

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
     }); 

return eventList;
}
```

It doesn't work since onComplete is a void method. I can read nothing from Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. The `onComplete()` method has an asynchronous behaviour which means that is called even before you are trying to add those objects of type `Event` to the `eventList` ArrayList. That's why your list is always empty outside that method. With other words, by the time you are returning the `eventList`, the data has not finished loading yet from the database, so to solve this, you need to create you own callback in order to wait for the data. So first you need to create an interface like this:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void onCallback(List<Event> eventList);
}
```

Then you need to create a method that is actually getting the data from the database. This method should look like this:

```
public void readData(MyCallback myCallback) {
    firestoreDB.collection("events")
        .whereEqualTo("type", eventType)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                        Event e = doc.toObject(Event.class);
                        e.setId(doc.getId());
                        eventList.add(e);
                    }
                    myCallback.onCallback(eventList);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }

     });
}
```

In the end just simply call `readData()` method and pass an instance of the `MyCallback` interface as an argument wherever you need it like this:

```
readData(new MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(List<Event> eventList) {
        Log.d("TAG", eventList.toString);
    }
});
```

This is the only way in which you can use the `eventList` outside `onComplete()` method. For more informations, you can take also a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)**.

Comment: Reply to Alex Mamo : Perfect, Thank you very much.I'm a novice, both in Android and Cloud Firestore. This is the most professional answer I have ever seen.

Comment: Thanks you for your appreciation! @MikeLin